# Exporting CSV file in R/R studio: permission denied

Tags: r, csv, permissions, admin

Cannot export CSV file using {write.csv} because of permission denial:

```
#create file
x <- c(1,3,4,3,5,7,5,8,2,5,7)
#export file
write.csv(x,file="whatever.csv")
```

I always get this error:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'whatever.csv': Permission denied
```

I tried opening R studio with admin rights, reboot PC, close eveything (including excel): permission still denied... any clues?

Comment: What operating system are you using? What is your working directory (`getwd()`)? Did you try to save the file in a different directory?

Answer (score 1):

Check your actual working directory with `getwd()`, set your working directory in the beginning with `setwd("C:\\users\\yourname\\")` or try to use a specific folder, like:

```
write.csv(x,file="C:\\user\\yourname\\whatever.csv")
```

Comment: The command should be `getwd()`. The folder structure looks different when not on Windows. But yeah, probably the error means no write permissions in the wd.

Comment: Oh sure i mean `getwd()`, I've corrected it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked when saving the file in the root folder (user/username) but not elsewhere (for example: user/username/Downloads). Any more ideas?

Comment: and if you're in the terminal you're allowed to save into this diretory? `touch user/username/Downloads/test` does work?

Comment: yes! it works with R alone (not Rstudio). Can Rstudio loose its admin rights?

Comment: and just to be clear, it's local RStudio and no RStudio server (that might run with an own user)?

Comment: PS: and could you try `library(data.table)` and `fwrite(x, "whatever.csv")`, just to check if the error also appears?

Comment: yes it is local Rstudio. Same problem with fwrite: it is ok in root folder (```user/username```) but not in (```user/username/Downloads```). I get this error: ```Permission denied: 'C:/Users/Benoit/Downloads/whatever2.csv'. Unable to create new file for writing (it does not exist already). Do you have permission to write here, is there space on the disk and does the path exist?```

Comment: is there anybody to help me with this unsolved problem please?